# asp.net/vb.net - can i store the user's reference to database?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I want to store the reference of customers to database , and when they login , they can view their own reference . but some how i still got some troubles , can you have a look ? and show me the solution , thanks in advance.

Table `aspnet_User`

![][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YpEL.jpg
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGX45.jpg

Table `Userinfo`, its a FK of table `aspnet_User`

![][2]

Here is my code :

```
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString2").ToString())
    conn.Open()

    'Customer Reference

    Dim chars As String = "1234ABCD"
    Dim orderref As String = ""
    Dim r As New Random()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 8
        orderref += chars.Substring(r.Next(chars.Length), 1)
    Next
    Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString2").ConnectionString
    Dim insertSql As String = "INSERT INTO Userinfo(UserId,HomeTown,HomePage,Orderref) VALUES(@UserId,@HomeTown,@HomePage,@Orderref)"
    Using myConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection)
        'myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", DBNull.Value)
         myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomeTown", DBNull.Value)
         myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomePage", DBNull.Value)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Orderref", orderref)

        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        myConnection.Close()
    End Using
```

it showed this error "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserId', table ' APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF.dbo.Userinfo'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated."

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not passing a value for the parameter `@UserId`, then your `INSERT` statement when executed against the database uses `NULL` and the table constraint triggers an error because the column `UserId` does not allow `NULL` values.

Uncomment this line:

```
'myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", DBNull.Value)
```

and pass in a real value, something besides `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: After creating an account , the column UserId will be stored to both   table aspnet_User ,Table Userinfo  ,  when users login in they can check their own reference , which means string orderref . therefore i can't pass any value to the column UserId , so is there any solution ?

Comment: @user2972074 - you need to relate the order reference number to the user, so you somehow need the user ID. Isn't the user ID known when the user attempts to login or retreivable at least?

Comment: this is the code to retrieve userid from aspnet_User                
        Dim currentUser As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser()
        
        Dim currentUserId As Guid = CType(currentUser.ProviderUserKey, Guid)
       
        e.Command.Parameters("@UserId").Value = currentUserId

Comment: @user2972074 - you need to either call the logic to get the `UserId` value before you save to the database or get the logged in person's `UserId` when they login and then store it in `Session` cache, either way you to need to lookup this value before you `INSERT` into the database.

Comment: as i said above the UserId will be saved to table Userinfo after the user creating their account , i need to compare the UserId in table Userinfo to the one in the table aspnet_User .

Comment: How can i   get the logged in person's UserId when they login and then store it in Session cache ??? thanks in advance

Comment: @user2972074 - please post your code for when the user logs in and is authenticated.

Comment: i just used createUserWizard, Login Form and the  table aspnet_User is automatically created , literally there is no code